# Domain ownership issue with Google AdSense even I have added ownership page

Tags: google, domains, google-adsense

I am facing domain ownership issue on my www.videoonfacebook.com site I have made [ownership page](http://www.videoonfacebook.com/domain-ownership.html) and resubmitted! but same reply?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if it's the real reason of your problem but you wrote "This text" instead of "This post".

Comment: These steps Adsense team said me to follow
1. Access the HTML source code of www.videoonfacebook.com.
2. Create a separate page on the site and paste the snippet:
<p>This post confirms my ownership of the site and that this site adheres to Google AdSense program policies and Terms and Conditions:  ca-pub-0063571225542644 </p>
3. Resubmit the application as described below after replacing www.videoonfacebook.com in the 'Website URL' with the URL of the page on which you have pasted the snippet.

Comment: So I added a domain ownership page on http://www.videoonfacebook.com/domain-ownership.html
BUT Same reply "domain ownership issue" from adsense team.
Is something wrong? Please help...

Comment: yes <p> not around the text but this is not a issue

Comment: dear Which Update?

Comment: @user848587 I updated my answer. It seems that you wrote "This text" instead of "This post".

Comment: Ok dear I am trying with the text --- "This post" -- Thank u

Comment: I have added verification post on home page and resubmitted but same reply from google adsense team?